# Selecting specific sequences from a column of sequences

Tags: r

I have data as follows:

```
data <- as.data.frame(c("[0;20;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;22;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;23;17;24;18;25;15;26;16;19]", 
                        "[0;21;16;27;15;28;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;29;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;30;18;31;17;19]", 
                        "[0;20;15;22;16;23;18;24;17;25;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;26;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;19]", 
                        "[0;20;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;22;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;23;15;24;16;25;17;26;18;19]", 
                        "[0;21;18;27;17;28;15;29;16;30;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;31;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;19]", 
                        "[0;20;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;22;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;23;15;24;16;25;17;26;18;19]", 
                        "[0;21;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;27;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;28;17;29;18;30;16;31;15;19]", 
                        "[0;20;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;22;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;23;16;24;15;25;18;26;17;19]", 
                        "[0;21;17;27;18;28;16;29;15;30;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;31;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;19]", 
                        "[0;20;15;22;16;23;18;24;17;25;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;26;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;19]", 
                        "[0;21;18;27;17;28;16;29;15;30;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;31;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;19]", 
                        "[0;20;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;22;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;23;18;24;17;25;16;26;15;19]", 
                        "[0;21;15;27;16;28;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;29;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;30;18;31;17;19]", 
                        "[0;21;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;27;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;28;15;29;16;30;18;31;17;19]", 
                        "[0;20;16;22;15;23;17;24;18;25;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;26;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;19]", 
                        "[0;20;18;22;17;23;15;24;16;25;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;26;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;19]", 
                        "[0;21;15;27;16;28;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;29;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;30;18;31;17;19]", 
                        "[0;21;15;27;16;28;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;29;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;30;17;31;18;19]", 
                        "[0;21;18;27;17;28;15;29;16;30;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;31;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;19]", 
                        "[0;20;16;22;15;23;17;24;18;25;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;26;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;19]", 
                        "[0;21;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;27;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;28;17;29;18;30;16;31;15;19]", 
                        "[0;20;16;22;15;23;18;24;17;25;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;26;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;19]", 
                        "[0;21;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;27;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;28;18;29;17;30;16;31;15;19]", 
                        "[0;20;15;22;16;23;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;24;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;25;18;26;17;19]", 
                        "[0;21;16;27;15;28;18;29;17;30;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;31;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;19]", 
                        "[0;20;15;22;16;23;17;24;18;25;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;26;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;19]"
))
```

What I would want to do is add an extra column to the data.frame, which just tells me, if the first criteria, the second criteria, both or neither of the following criteria are fulfilled:

1. Rows for which `17`, comes later in the sequence than `15`.
2. Rows for which `18`, comes later in the sequence than `16`.

Something like:

```
Neither
Both
First
Second
Neither
Both
Both
Second
```

Could anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a new column you can include the conditions in `case_when` -

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(result = case_when(grepl('15.*17', col) & grepl('16.*18', col) ~ 'Both', 
                            grepl('15.*17', col) ~ 'First', 
                            grepl('16.*18', col) ~ 'Second', 
                            TRUE ~ 'Neither'))
```

If you want to subset the data, based on the conditions, you can use `grepl` to look for the pattern -

```
data1 <- data[grepl('15.*17', data$col), , drop = FALSE]
data2 <- data[grepl('16.*18', data$col), , drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was just editing my question, but I was already afraid that someone would answer before.  Would it also be possible to add a column, which tells me if the criteria apply. I can also just make a new question if you prefer.

Comment: You are the best!

Comment: Thanks again, I am getting the following error. Any idea why? `Error: Problem with mutate() input result.
x cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
i Input result is case_when(...).
Run rlang::last_error() to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: Yeah..that is because in the data you have shared there is no column name (or a very weird one). I used `col` as an example and used it as `data.frame(col = ......)`.