# Selecting specific sequences from a column of sequences, with a maximum distance in between

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, grepl

I have data as follows:

```
data <- as.data.frame(c("[0;20;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;22;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;23;17;24;18;25;15;26;16;19]", 
                        "[0;21;16;27;15;28;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;29;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;30;18;31;17;19]", 
                        "[0;20;15;22;16;23;18;24;17;25;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;26;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;19]", 
                        "[0;20;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;22;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;23;15;24;16;25;17;26;18;19]", 
                        "[0;21;18;27;17;28;15;29;16;30;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;31;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;19]", 
                        "[0;20;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;22;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;23;15;24;16;25;17;26;18;19]", 
                        "[0;21;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;27;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;28;17;29;18;30;16;31;15;19]", 
                        "[0;20;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;22;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;23;16;24;15;25;18;26;17;19]", 
                        "[0;21;17;27;18;28;16;29;15;30;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;31;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;19]", 
                        "[0;20;15;22;16;23;18;24;17;25;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;26;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;19]", 
                        "[0;21;18;27;17;28;16;29;15;30;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;31;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;19]", 
                        "[0;20;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;22;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;23;18;24;17;25;16;26;15;19]", 
                        "[0;21;15;27;16;28;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;29;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;30;18;31;17;19]", 
                        "[0;21;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;27;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;28;15;29;16;30;18;31;17;19]", 
                        "[0;20;16;22;15;23;17;24;18;25;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;26;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;19]", 
                        "[0;20;18;22;17;23;15;24;16;25;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;26;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;19]", 
                        "[0;21;15;27;16;28;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;29;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;30;18;31;17;19]", 
                        "[0;21;15;27;16;28;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;29;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;30;17;31;18;19]", 
                        "[0;21;18;27;17;28;15;29;16;30;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;31;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;19]", 
                        "[0;20;16;22;15;23;17;24;18;25;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;26;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;19]", 
                        "[0;21;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;27;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;28;17;29;18;30;16;31;15;19]", 
                        "[0;20;16;22;15;23;18;24;17;25;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;26;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;19]", 
                        "[0;21;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;27;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;28;18;29;17;30;16;31;15;19]", 
                        "[0;20;15;22;16;23;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;24;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;25;18;26;17;19]", 
                        "[0;21;16;27;15;28;18;29;17;30;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;31;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;19]", 
                        "[0;20;15;22;16;23;17;24;18;25;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;26;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;19]"
))
```

What I wanted to do is add an extra column to the data.frame, which tells me, if the first criteria, the second criteria, both or neither of the following criteria are fulfilled:

1. Rows for which `17`, comes later in the sequence than `15`.
2. Rows for which `18`, comes later in the sequence than `16`.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68543715/selecting-specific-sequences-from-a-column-of-sequences), Ronak gave the following, very nice solution:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(result = case_when(grepl('15.*17', col) & grepl('16.*18', col) ~ 'Both', 
                            grepl('15.*17', col) ~ 'First', 
                            grepl('16.*18', col) ~ 'Second', 
                            TRUE ~ 'Neither'))
```

I realised a bit later, that I wanted to slightly change the conditions;

1. Rows for which `17`, comes later in the sequence than `15`, **but** with a maximum of three other numbers in between.
2. Rows for which `18`, comes later in the sequence than `16`, **but** with a maximum of one other number in between.

I have been looking at the [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html), but I cannot really figure out how to adapt the pattern. This mostly has to do with the fact that I don't know how many double and single digit numbers there are in between.

I thought for example to do something like `/^[.]{0,10}$/` but I do not know how many characters will be in between. Could anyone help?

Comment: What if 17 comes after 15 with less than 3 numbers in between, but then again after more than three numbers? For example, is the first condition true for `"[15, 17, 17, 17, 17]"`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Thank you for your comment. Although I can see that this would in other cases result in issues, in my particular case, the numbers `15`,`16`, `17` and `18`, are limited to one occurrence in all sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
data %>%
  mutate(result = case_when(grepl('15(;\\d+;){,3}17', seq) & grepl('16(;\\d+;){,1}18', seq) ~ 'Both', 
                            grepl('15(;\\d+;){,3}17', seq) ~ 'First', 
                            grepl('16(;\\d+;){,1}18', seq) ~ 'Second', 
                            TRUE ~ 'Neither'))
    seq  result
1  [0;20;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;22;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;23;17;24;18;25;15;26;16;19] Neither
2  [0;21;16;27;15;28;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;29;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;30;18;31;17;19] Neither
3  [0;20;15;22;16;23;18;24;17;25;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;26;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;19]  Second
4  [0;20;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;22;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;23;15;24;16;25;17;26;18;19] Neither
5  [0;21;18;27;17;28;15;29;16;30;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;31;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;19] Neither
6  [0;20;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;22;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;23;15;24;16;25;17;26;18;19] Neither
7  [0;21;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;27;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;28;17;29;18;30;16;31;15;19] Neither
8  [0;20;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;22;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;23;16;24;15;25;18;26;17;19] Neither
9  [0;21;17;27;18;28;16;29;15;30;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;31;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;19] Neither
10 [0;20;15;22;16;23;18;24;17;25;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;26;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;19]  Second
11 [0;21;18;27;17;28;16;29;15;30;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;31;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;19] Neither
12 [0;20;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;22;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;23;18;24;17;25;16;26;15;19] Neither
13 [0;21;15;27;16;28;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;29;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;30;18;31;17;19] Neither
14 [0;21;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;27;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;28;15;29;16;30;18;31;17;19]  Second
15 [0;20;16;22;15;23;17;24;18;25;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;26;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;19]   First
16 [0;20;18;22;17;23;15;24;16;25;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;26;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;19] Neither
17 [0;21;15;27;16;28;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;29;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;30;18;31;17;19] Neither
18 [0;21;15;27;16;28;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;29;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;30;17;31;18;19] Neither
19 [0;21;18;27;17;28;15;29;16;30;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;31;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;19] Neither
20 [0;20;16;22;15;23;17;24;18;25;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;26;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;19]   First
21 [0;21;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;27;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;28;17;29;18;30;16;31;15;19] Neither
22 [0;20;16;22;15;23;18;24;17;25;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;26;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;19] Neither
23 [0;21;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;27;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;28;18;29;17;30;16;31;15;19] Neither
24 [0;20;15;22;16;23;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;24;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;25;18;26;17;19] Neither
25 [0;21;16;27;15;28;18;29;17;30;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;31;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;19] Neither
26 [0;20;15;22;16;23;17;24;18;25;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;26;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;19] Neither
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I think you only switched the max distance around. This is the `{,3}` part right?

Comment: Yes, `{,3}` is a quantifying expression repeating the prior substring **at most** three times